# Why doesn't send stop this Task in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

If I have the below module defined and I do the following:

1) `{:ok, pid} = ExampleTaskShutdown.start()`
2) `ExampleTaskShutdown.stop(pid)`

Why does ExampleTaskShutdown#stop/1 need Process.exit(..) to stop the task? Why doesn't using `send(...)` in ExampleTaskShutdown#stop/1 (as in the commented code below) work to shutdown the task?  Is it because the anonymous function in Task.start(..) its own process that is not the pid defined by ExampleTaskShutdown.start()?

```
  defmodule ExampleTaskShutdown do
  @moduledoc """
  Shutdown the task
  """

  def start() do
    Task.start(fn ->
      receive do
        :stop ->
          :timer.sleep(1000)
          exit(:shutdown)
      end
    end)
  end

  @doc """
  Stop the process.
  """
  def stop(pid) do
    # send(pid, :stop)
    Process.exit(pid, :stop)
  end
end
```

EDIT: Added a test - the process doesn't seem to die in the ex_unit test if using `send(..)` and running `mix test`. Using Elixir 1.6.6 and Erlang 21.x

```
defmodule ExampleTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  test "process is dead after :stop" do
    {:ok, pid} = ExampleTaskShutdown.start()
    ExampleTaskShutdown.stop(pid)
    refute Process.alive?(pid)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The task spawned pretty fine exits when `:stop` is sent:

```rb
defmodule ExampleTaskShutdown do
  def start() do
    Task.start(fn ->
      receive do
        :stop ->
          IO.puts "Stopping..."
          Process.sleep(100)
          exit(:shutdown)
      end 
    end) 
  end 

  def stop(pid) do
    send(pid, :stop)
    # Process.exit(pid, :stop)
  end 
end

with {:ok, pid} <- ExampleTaskShutdown.start() do
  ExampleTaskShutdown.stop(pid)
  Process.sleep(200) # to wait until task finishes
  Process.alive?(pid) # false
end

#⇒ Stopping...
#⇒ false
```

---

> Why it failed in test?

In your test you `refute` **immediately** and it obviously fails because on `receive :stop` your code has a one second `sleep` before `exit(:shutdown)`. `Process.exit` shuts everything down immediately and `refute` succeeds. Put `Process.sleep(1_000)` right before `refute` and your test will pass.

Comment: thanks @mudasobwa, it seemed to happen in ex_unit tests only then (I never checked in the iex shell)

Comment: I doubt it is happening in tests either. Please update the question with the related context.

Comment: hi @mudasobwa, I just ran `mix test` and it happens there although not when running in the iex shell.  I listed the Elixir and Erlang versions if that helps

Comment: In your test you `refute` **immediately** and it obviously fails because on `receive :stop` your code has a one second `sleep`. `Process.exit` shuts everything down immediately and `refute` succeeds. Put `Process.sleep(1_000)` right before `refute` and your test will pass.